# Codeception API Tests heads not sending

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I have the following code.

```
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Test API Endpoint');
$I->authenticateAsUserById(1); 
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$I->sendPOST('example', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Along with the following api.suite.yml

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
           url: 127.0.0.1
           depends: PhpBrowser
           part: Json
        - Doctrine2:
           depends: Symfony2
        - \Helper\Api
        - Symfony2:
           app_path: 'app'
           var_path: 'var'
           environment: 'test'
           debug: false
```

However when running the test in Verbose mode the output of the command appears to not be sending the request headers.

```
[Request] POST 127.0.0.1/example {"foo":"bar"}]}
  [Request Headers] []
[Page] 127.0.0.1/example
[Response] 400
  [Request Cookies] []
[Response Headers] {"Server":["nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)"],"Date":["Fri, 15 Dec 2017 23:18:13 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/html"],"Content-Length":["182"],"Connection":["close"]}
  [Response] <html>
  <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
  <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
  <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is turn is appearing to have the server return a bad request.

Has anyone run into this problem using Codeception and the Rest Bundle?

## Edit

This appears to be an issue with a conflict between the Symfony2 Plugin and PHPBrowser, where the symfony is disabling these features.

Comment: The REST module requires the PhpBrowser module. So try to add "PhpBrowser" in your api.suite.yml enabled-array directly after REST.